# Python Sub-Process in Emacs Not Getting Input or Sending Back Results

Tags: python, asynchronous, emacs, subprocess

**BACKGROUND**

I am writing a small package to farm out Emacs Lisp computations to a Python sub-process so I don't have to reproduce complicated numerical routines.  For my particular problem, I need Python as a sub-process because I need to maintain certain time-consuming computations done by Python.  For small things, I can do things perfectly fine by sending computations to Python via shell commands.  However, I DO need the sub-process for more intensive stuff.

**SETUP**

1. GNU Emacs 25.2.1 under Windows 10
2. Anaconda's Python 3.5 distribution for Windows 10

**SAMPLE RUN**

From any buffer, hit M-x ielm. This will bring up the IELM Emacs Lisp shell.  Here is a transcript of my session a few minutes ago:

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (setq PyProc (start-process "python" "*python*" "python"))
#<process python>
ELISP> (process-list)
(#<process python> #<process ielm>)

ELISP> (process-status PyProc)
run
ELISP> (process-type PyProc)
real
ELISP> (process-send-string PyProc "1+1")
nil
ELISP> (process-send-eof PyProc)
#<process python>
```

As you run the above Emacs Lisp in IELM (or whatever way you want), you can watch the *python* buffer.  Nothing displays.  However, as you clearly see, I can kill the process and query its running status.

**PROBLEM**

Why is the Python process unable to display ANYTHING in the *python* buffer?  I have done this with MySQL to a remote server (using the local install of MySQL) with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some investigations.  I have a partial workaround.  However, I still have not clue why the original attempt using start-process does not work.

I know that one can use

```
M-x run-python
```

to launch an inferior Python process.  One can then use use

```
(process-send-string PyProc "1+1\n")
```

where *PyProc* is the symbol holding your process object. This sends the command to the inferior process and presses return.  The strange thing is that the "1+1\n" does not display in the *Python* buffer.  The returned value does display.  Storing the point before and after the output, it is then easy to retrieve Python's output.  Here is a partial snippet:

```
;; Run inferior Python process (assumes you have Python properly installed)
(setq PyProc (run-python))
;; Send a carriage return. There is some issue when the process first starts
(process-send-string PyProc "\n")
;; Store the point prior to sending a command
(setq PyPM (with-current-buffer "*Python*"
     (point)
     )
  )
;; Send a command to Python
(process-send-string PyProc "1+1;\n")
;; Get the result of the computation
(setq Result (with-current-buffer "*Python*"
               (buffer-substring-no-properties PyPM
                                       (- (point) 5)
               ) 
       )
  )
```

Evaluation of *Result* gives you

```
Result -> "2"
```

You can terminate the process using

```
(process-send-eof PyProc)
```

Still don't know why I cannot simply use start-process.

Answer (score 0):

In my first answer above, I resorted to

```
(setq PyProc (run-python))
```

to run Python as an inferior process since I had not been able to launch Python using the function start-process.  Per the GNU Emacs documentation, there can be lots of issues with DOS programs because of the way they handle the stdin and stdout.  However, python provides a "-i" command line flag that solves the problem on windows.

All you have to do is:

```
(setq PyProc (start-process "python" "*Python*" "python" "-i"))
(process-send-string PyProc "1+1;\n")
```

If you switch to buffer *Python*, you will see "2" as the result of the computation. If you want to see this work nicely, simply spit your window vertically by using C-x 3. Switch to *Python* on the right and run your code from the left buffer.

When you are ready to kill the Python process, just

```
(process-send-eof PyProc)
```

Kill you buffer to clean up.  Hope this helps those trying to control processes on the Windows platform.